# Does one bentch on an achila gasa?

Tags: halacha-theory, bentching, eating

After eating an excessive amount to a point that would be termed [achila gasa](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%90%D7%9B%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%94_%D7%92%D7%A1%D7%94) which I will leave undefined, does a person have an obligation to recite grace after meals (or another bracha achrona as appropriate)?

Comment: Is the case where they started full or started hungry and they ate until full and continued eating more? If the latter I don't understand the question. Why would further eating achila gasa eliminate the previous obligation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mishne Berurah 197:28

> מי שהיה שבע קודם שאכל ואכל אכילה גסה שלא היה צריך לאותה אכילה אעפ"כ **אם
>   נהנה גרונו מאותה אכילה מברך עליו לפניו ולאחריו** ומוציא אחרים ואם נפשו
>   קצה עליו **ואינו נהנה גרונו** **אינו ראוי לברך לא לפניה ולא לאחריה** לפי שזו
>   אינה חשובה אכילה כלל לכל מצות שבתורה כמו שנתבאר בסימן תע"ו ובסימן
>   תרי"ב

One who was already satisfied before eating, yet still ate *achilah gassa* - if he had *hanaas g'rono*, he must make *berachos* both before and after. If, however, he is disgusted by the food and doesnt have any *hanaah* at all, he does not bless neither before nor after.